# 301 Redirect all "Site.com/Postname.html/xyz" to "Site.com/Postname.html"

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

About 1000 links have the wrong structure similar to the link below.

> https://url.com/1200/postname.html/xyz1a2b3

Now I want to transfer all these links using the redirect 301 to their correct address like this:

> https://url.com/1200/postname.html

How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RewriteRule` to redirect your URLs.
Concerning your URLs, you need to use `([0-9]+)` for number part in URL and `([A-Za-z0-9-]*)` for number and character part.

Like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]*).html/([A-Za-z0-9-]*) https://url.com/$1/$2.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation with your code in answers.

Comment: @LéaGris  Ok I've added the description